# Points $p_o, p_l, ... , p_k$ are affinely independent if and only if the rank of the matrix of their barycentric coordinates equals k + 1.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Points $p_o, p_l, ... , p_k$ are affinely independent if and only if
the rank of the matrix of their barycentric coordinates equals k + 1.

So I came across this theorem while reading about affine space and the proof for the same is given by the author as follow:

[image]

[image]

I am having confusion with a matrix where it says the rank does not change after adding all the column and then obtains a matrice where subtraction is done. Could someone please explain what the author has done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of all columns is the all ones vector. Replacing the first column with the sum of all columns yields
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & x_{01} & \cdots & x_{0n} \\ 1 & x_{11} & \cdots & x_{1n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_{k1} & \cdots & x_{kn}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Subtracting the first row from each of the other rows leads to the given matrix. (This also does not change the rank.)